# Is there a simpler way to decode this json in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, interface, type-assertion

I am trying to parse some JSON from Jira to variables. This is using the go-jira package (https://godoc.org/github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira)

Currently I have some code to get the developer:

`dev := jiraIssue.Fields.Unknowns["customfield_11343"].(map[string]interface{})["name"]`

and `team := jiraIssue.Fields.Unknowns["customfield_12046"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["value"]`

to get the team they are a part of from.

Getting the team they are on is a bit gross, is there a cleaner way to get the team besides having to type assert, set the index, then type assert again?

Here is the complete json (modified but structure is same, its way too long):

```
{    
 "expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
   "id":"136944",
   "self":"https://jira.redacted.com/rest/api/2/issue/136944",
   "key":"RM-2506",
   "fields":{  
      "customfield_11343":{  
         "self":"https://redacted.com/rest/api/2/user?username=flast",
         "name":"flast",
         "key":"flast",
         "emailAddress":"flast@redacted.com",
         "displayName":"first last",
         "active":true,
         "timeZone":"Europe/London"
      },
      "customfield_12046":[  
         {  
            "self":"https://jira.redacted.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/12045",
            "value":"diy",
            "id":"12045"
         }
      ],

   }
```

Thanks

Comment: The usual approach is to define Go types that match the structure of the JSON and decode to the type.  Show the complete JSON.

Comment: added more of the json

Comment: The custom fields have different value types.  Is the type determined by the name of the field ("customfield_11343" is an example) or something else?

Comment: that is determined by Jira themselves

Comment: Are the value types arbitrary, or is there a documented mapping between the field names and the value types?

Comment: from what I can tell its pretty much arbitrary. jira offers a very high level way of choosing customfields and it populates the types and the entries

Comment: Dave Johnson in his answer is on the right track in my opinion, however you do not need reflection to check whether the value is an array or an object, all you need is to take a look at the first byte. https://play.golang.org/p/GiVx60gY-ng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I go about problems like this is:

1. Copy some JSON with things I am interested in and paste it into https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
2. Remove fields that aren´t of interest.
3. Just read the data and unmarshal.

You might end up with something like this given the two custom fields of interest, but you can cut the structure down further if you just need the name.

```json
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Fields struct {
        Customfield11343 struct {
            Self         string `json:"self"`
            Name         string `json:"name"`
            Key          string `json:"key"`
            EmailAddress string `json:"emailAddress"`
            DisplayName  string `json:"displayName"`
            Active       bool   `json:"active"`
            TimeZone     string `json:"timeZone"`
        } `json:"customfield_11343"`
        Customfield12046 []struct {
            Self  string `json:"self"`
            Value string `json:"value"`
            ID    string `json:"id"`
        } `json:"customfield_12046"`
    } `json:"fields"`
}
```

The effect you get is that all extra information in the feed is discarded, but you get the data you want very cleanly.

Comment: hmm.. so what go-jira does is return an IssueFields type, with those customfields in the "Unknowns" data. I assume i would need to do something similar to this but get the data from the MarshalMap of the Unknowns into my created struct?

Comment: wow okay, so all along there was a .Values() method of the Unknowns type.. and you can access fields like this `dev, exists := jiraIssue.Fields.Unknowns.Value("customfield_11343/name")` . I appreciate the learning from the answers though

Comment: Cool :-) I think you can also do a NewRawRequest t if you want the library to mostly go away but still use it for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

This is a tough one since the second one is in an array form. It makes it hard to use a map.

For the first one, it's simple enough to use:

```golang
type JiraCustomField struct {
    Self         string `json:"self"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Key          string `json:"key"`
    EmailAddress string `json:"emailAddress"`
    DisplayName  string `json:"displayName"`
    Active       bool   `json:"active"`
    TimeZone     string `json:"timeZone"`
}
type JiraPayload struct {
    Expand string                     `json:"expand"`
    ID     string                     `json:"id"`
    Key    string                     `json:"key"`
    Fields map[string]JiraCustomField `json:"fields"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/y8-g6r0kInV

Specifically this part `Fields map[string]JiraCustomField` for the second case it looks like you need it in an array form like `Fields map[string][]JiraCustomField`.

In a case like this, I think you'll need to make your own Unmarshaler. This is a good tutorial: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/

What you could do with your custom Unmarshal/marshaler, is use the Reflection package and check if it's an array or a struct. If it's a struct then put it into an array, and store it in `Fields map[string][]JiraCustomField`.