# How to access map[string]interface {}?

Tags: go

How can i programmatically access the `msg` value "Design" in the go language structure shown below?

[image]

after `subIssues[28].Fields.Unknowns["customfield_11801"]` i dont find a language construct to access the data structure.

Comment: Do you need a map, or can you use a struct instead?

Comment: I'm working with https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira. That library creates such structures and i have to work with what query result data structures that library provides.

Comment: There are easy ways to convert them to structs.

Comment: Would that be feasible?

Comment: If that can be converted into a struct for simpler access I'm open to that.

Comment: Is it that complicated to just access the existing data structure that its easier to write like 40 lines of code and create a mirror struct and fill it? Seams not reasonable. Especially as there is no need to create such structs.

Comment: I found out my question closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366169/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-decode-this-json-in-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert into a struct and work with that, have a look at this repo: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure.

And if you want to do it your self, something like this: (Adjust implementation to match your project)

```
func SetField(obj interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)

    if !structFieldValue.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("No such field: %s in obj", name)
    }

    if !structFieldValue.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot set %s field value", name)
    }

    structFieldType := structFieldValue.Type()
    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if structFieldType != val.Type() {
        return errors.New("Provided value type didn't match obj field type")
    }

    structFieldValue.Set(val)
    return nil
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Age  int64
}

func (s *MyStruct) FillStruct(m map[string]interface{}) error {
    for k, v := range m {
        err := SetField(s, k, v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    myData := make(map[string]interface{})
    myData["Name"] = "Tony"
    myData["Age"] = int64(23)

    result := &MyStruct{}
    err := result.FillStruct(myData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```